# Derivative of determinant is 0: meaning/conclusions

Tags: matrices, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Suppose we consider a matrix $A(z)\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Then let $det(A(z))$ be its determinant. If $det(A(z))=0$, we can draw several conclusions:

1. 0 is an eigenvalue of the matrix A(z),
2. $A(z)\cdot v=0$, where $v$ is the eigenvector to the eigenvalue 0,
3. A(z) is not invertible

and so on.

Now considering $\frac{d}{dz}det(A(z))=0$ (derivative of determinant to $z$ is 0), are there any conclusions that can be drawn there?

I've done a lot of searching but haven't found anything helpful. Maybe someone knows something about this.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula

Comment: I know the Jacobi formula, but i am more interested in statements like we have for the $det(A)$, like something with eigenvalues or eigenvectors.

Comment: Your second point is not fully correct. You can just say that 0 is an eigenvalue but nothing about its multiplicity and there is no such thing as "the" eigenvector but rather "an" eigenvector associated with the zero eigenvalue. If the derivative of the determinant is zero, then it just means that the determinant is independent of $z$. This is equivalent to say that the product of all the eigenvalues is independent of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobi formula tells us that
$$\eqalign{
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\t{\operatorname{Tr}}
\l &= \det(A) \quad\implies\quad
\dot\l &= \l\,\t(A^{-1}\dot A) \\
}$$
Therefore $\,\dot\l=0\,$ means that either
$$\eqalign{
\l &= 0 \qquad{\bf or}\qquad \t(A^{-1}\dot A)  \\
}$$
You already know what $\,\l=0\,$ implies.

Assuming  $\,\l\ne 0\,$ implies that $A^{-1}$ exists but the trace of $(A^{-1}\dot A)$ is zero.

Certainly, if $\dot A=0$ then the trace will be zero,
but there are other possibilities.

Comment: It is not fully correct since the case $\lambda=0$ does not arise since there is a factor of $1/\lambda$ in the inverse matrix that cancels out with the $\lambda$ term.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to derive the following formula and then draw possible conclusions. Let $A_1(z), ... , A_n(z)$ be the $n$ columns of $A(z)$. Then :

$$\frac{d}{dz} \det(A(z)) =\sum_{k=1}^n \det( A_1(z), ..., \frac{d A_k(z)}{dz}, ... , A_n(z))$$

where $(A_1(z), ...,  \frac{d A_k(z)}{dz}, ... , A_n(z))$ is the $A(z)$ matrix where the $k^{th}$ column is replaced by its element-wise derivative.

Comment: Thanks for the formula, but i don’t see any connection to eigenvalues or eigenvectors. :(